# Delete all files with no name but variable extension

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, dos, directory-structure

How do I create a batch command that will recursively go through my folders and remove all files that:

1. Have no name before the extension
2. The extension begins with `._`

For example, `._Icon` or `._Public`

This script has to run on boot and preferably hides in the background but I can probably figure that out once I have a batch script.

The directory in question is `D:\Dropbox`

Can this be done with batch scripting or do I need something else? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
pushd d:\dropbox
del /s ._*
popd
```

You can establish this .bat as a scheduled task, which will run on boot.

Comment: `del "d:\dropbox\._*" /s` <--- Use this which is safer, in case the `pushd` fails.